# Position of the incoming datatable rows

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, datatable, webix

Trying to load the data from the inline data source to the top of the datatable. 
`pos` property works well for every position except the mentioned one.

For example,

```
var data = [{title:1},{title:2}]
webix.ui({
  view:"datatable", id:"table", autoConfig:true, data:grid_data 
});

$$("table").parse({data:data, pos:0}) // should be the first
```

should add the data to the top, but it appears at the bottom of the datatable. Any other value of `pos` will work properly. So I'm a bit confused - am I doing something wrong or is there any other way to do this?

[Snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/56053535)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it happens, but as another solution, you can iterate `add` method through the dataset. I also investigate a bit, it will be useful to avoid multiple re-rendering (`add` triggers also `refresh` to show the added element) using `blockEvent` method to the table's datastore:

```
$$("table").data.blockEvent(); // table.data gives access to the table's datastore
for ( var i = 0; i<3; i++)
  $$("table").add(data[i], i);

$$("table").data.unblockEvent();
$$("table").refresh();
```

[**snippet**](http://webix.com/snippet/b3922c04)